# \lstnewenvironment does not work

Tags: listings, environments, verbatim

In the following codes, I try to make my `lstlisting` environment(named `drenv`) by `\lstnewenvironment`. It fails to pass compilation. I'd like to know why and how to make it work.

**code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xparse}
%------------------------------
\newsavebox{\mybox}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{dr}{O{}m}
{
  \begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
  \begin{minipage}{#2}
}
{
  \end{minipage}
  \end{lrbox}
  \colorbox{#1}{\usebox\mybox}
}
\lstnewenvironment{drenv}[3][]
 {
   \dr[#2]{#3}
   \lstset{#1}
 }
 {
   \enddr
 }
%------------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{drenv}{red}{5in}
\rule{2in}{5pt}
\end{drenv}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use tcolorbox for this job

Comment: Thank you @egreg tcolorbox is too heavy for this item.